# Join one column on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am having trouble creating aliases in a join. Can I get assistance with the proper way to join one column on two?

**Table Name: [TheERP].[dbo].[Employees]**

Table Column1: EmployeeID

Table Column2: EFullname

**Table Name: [TheERP].[dbo].[Jobs]**

Table Column1: JobID

Table Column2: JobAcctManID

Table Column3: JobSuperID

**Desired Results:**

Table Column1: FullNameJobAcctMan

Table Column2: FullNameJobSuper

Comment: from [TheERP].[dbo].[Employees]

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and consider expanding on your question.

Comment: Please edit your question so the stackoverflow users unsderstand what you are asking. Also don''t make comments which are actually edits of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly... Join to the same table twice

```
SELECT ae.FullName as FullNameJobAcctMan, se.FullName as FullNameJobSuper   
FROM [TheERP].[dbo].[Jobs] j
Join [TheERP].[dbo].[Employees] ae ON ae.EmployeeID  = j.JobAcctManID
Join [TheERP].[dbo].[Employees] se ON se.EmployeeID = j.JobSuperID
```

If `Jobs.JobAcctManID` Or `Jobs.JobSuperID` could be null then you could use a `left` join and optionally replace `null` values with `ISNULL` ...

```
SELECT ISNULL(ae.FullName, '') as FullNameJobAcctMan, 
ISNULL(se.FullName, '') as FullNameJobSuper   
FROM [TheERP].[dbo].[Jobs] j
LEFT Join [TheERP].[dbo].[Employees] ae ON ae.EmployeeID  = j.JobAcctManID
LEFT Join [TheERP].[dbo].[Employees] se ON se.EmployeeID = j.JobSuperID
```